# zkSync hardhat, I can't connect different address to contract

Tags: blockchain, ethers.js, hardhat, zksync

I have some problems when try to test my smart contract in zkSync with hardhat, I can't connect different address to contract like in ethers.js:
contract.connect(otherAddress).someFunction();

when I do the same in zkSync I get this:

**Error: missing response (requestBody="{"method":"eth_gasPrice","params":[],"id":46,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}", requestMethod="POST", serverError={"errno":-61,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":3050} url="http://localhost:3050", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)**

```
async function deploy() {const provider = Provider.getDefaultProvider();
    const owner = new Wallet(RICH_WALLET_PK, provider);
    const user = new Wallet(RICH_WALLET_PK1, provider);

    const deployer = new Deployer(hre, owner);

    const FarmArtifact = await deployer.loadArtifact("Farm");
    const TokenAArtifacts = await deployer.loadArtifact("TokenA");
    const TokenBArtifacts = await deployer.loadArtifact("TokenB");

    const tokenAContract = await deployer.deploy(TokenAArtifacts);
    const tokenBContract = await deployer.deploy(TokenBArtifacts);
    const farmContract = await deployer.deploy(FarmArtifact, [tokenAContract.address, tokenBContract.address]);

    return {tokenAContract, tokenBContract, farmContract, deployer, user, owner}}

    describe("TokenA", () => {
    it("test", async () => {

        const {tokenAContract, tokenBContract, RICH_WALLET_PK, farmContract, user, 
        deployer, owner} = await deploy();

        await tokenBContract.mint(user.address, "100000000000000000000");
        await tokenAContract.approve(farmContract.address, "10000000000000000000");
        await farmContract.depositRewardToken("10000000000000000000");
        await tokenBContract.approve(farmContract.address, "10000000000000000000");
        await farmContract.connect(user).stake("10000000000000000000", {value: ethers.utils.formatUnits("1000", "wei")});
    })
})
```

```
hardhat.config
const config = {
    zksolc: {
        version: "latest", // Uses latest available in https://github.com/matter-labs/zksolc-bin/
        settings: {}
    },
    defaultNetwork: "zkSyncTestnet",
    networks: {
        hardhat: {
            zksync: false
        },
        goerli: {
            url: "https://goerli.com/api/abcdef12345",
            zksync: false
        },
        mainnet: {
            url: "https://ethereum.mainnet.com/api/abcdef12345",
            zksync: false
        },
        zkSyncTestnet: process.env.NODE_ENV === "test"
            ? {
                url: "http://localhost:8011",
                ethNetwork: "http://localhost:8545",
                zksync: true
            }
            : {
                url: "https://testnet.era.zksync.dev",
                ethNetwork: "goerli", // or a Goerli RPC endpoint from Infura/Alchemy/Chainstack etc.
                zksync: true,
                verifyURL: 'https://zksync2-testnet-explorer.zksync.dev/contract_verification'
            }
    },
    solidity: {
        version: "0.8.19"
    }
    // OTHER SETTINGS...
};
```

Comment: This looks like a problem of the provider. Your localhost is refusing the connection for some reason. You can try using zksync public testnet and see if it solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks for answer, i have yet one question, maybe you know how to skip time in tests, like "mine()" or "time"?

Comment: You can use `await provider.send('evm_mine', []);` to mine a block, and `await provider.send('evm_increaseTime', [10]);` to jump 10 seconds in time.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it does not work in any direction, when I am using await provider.send('evm_increaseTime', [10]); it give me 
Error: missing response (requestBody="{\"method\":\"evm_mine\",\"params\":[100],\"id\":46,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", serverError={"errno":-61,"code":"ECONNREFUSED","syscall":"connect","address":"127.0.0.1","port":3050}, url="http://localhost:3050", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1), the second one the same.
Can you please explain or give link to read about how using zksync public testnet, I am a new one so have real problems with understanding

Comment: I have attached hardhat config in first message, thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure why it's trying to connect to port 3050, when it's not in your config.